# Spark failed to delete temp directory

Tags: java, apache-spark, bigdata

I am trying to submit spark program from cmd in windows 10 with below mentioned command:

```
spark-submit --class abc.Main --master local[2] C:\Users\arpitbh\Desktop\AmdocsIDE\workspace\Line_Count_Spark\target\Line_Count_Spark-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

but after running this i am getting error:

```
17/05/02 11:56:57 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory C:\Users\arpitbh\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-03f14dbe-1802-40ca-906c-af8de0f462f9
17/05/02 11:56:57 ERROR ShutdownHookManager: Exception while deleting Spark temp dir: C:\Users\arpitbh\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-03f14dbe-1802-40ca-906c-af8de0f462f9
java.io.IOException: Failed to delete: C:\Users\arpitbh\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-03f14dbe-1802-40ca-906c-af8de0f462f9
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.deleteRecursively(Utils.scala:1010)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:216)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1951)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.runAll(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anon$2.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:178)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:54)
```

I have also checked JIRA of apache spark, This defect has been marked solved but no solution is mentioned. Please help.

```
package abc;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;


public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        SparkConf conf =new SparkConf().setAppName("Line_Count").setMaster("local[2]");
        JavaSparkContext ctx= new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        JavaRDD<String> textLoadRDD = ctx.textFile("C:/spark/README.md");
        System.out.println(textLoadRDD.count());
        System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");

    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see here [how to format code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Can you provide your code ?

Comment: i have updated my code in correct format. Please check

Comment: I run into the same issue just by exiting spark-shell, or by running any of the examples. It is not a permission issue because I also tried specifying a different working dir with --conf spark.local.dir. If anyone has a solution, please share.

Answer (score 1):

I believed, you are trying to execute program without setting up user variables HADOOP_HOME or SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS.
I had same issued, resolved it by creating variables e.g HADOOP_HOME-> C:\Hadoop, SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS->C:\tmp\spark

Comment: I've set both variables and still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

this is probably because you are instantiating the SparkContext without a SPARK_HOME or HUPA_HOME that allows the program to find winutils.exe in the bin directory. I found that when I went from

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
```

to

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext("local[*], "programname", 
System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), System.getenv("JARS"));
```

the error went away.